# CKEDITOR Not Working with Simple Modal jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, simplemodal

I have inserted CKEDITOR inside the [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) jQuery plugin. The editor is visible but I am unable to insert any text within the text area. I think its disabled/inactive. I have tried using the onShow call back function (shown below) to initialize the CKEditor plugin but it doesn't seem to work.

```
onShow: function (dialog) {
    ckeditor();
}
```

Maybe its the way I have initialized it that is wrong. Anyway, could someone please assist in solving this problem? I have searched for the solution to this issue for over a week. Some answers that I have come across do not provide a straight forward solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sample on JSFiddle would be gratefully welcome. No one will spend a time on trying to set it up ;)